# ffi-napi support with Electron 27.1.2

Tags: electron

We wish to use latest version 27.1.2 of Electron, however we observed modules 'ref-napi' and 'ffi-napi' do not support the latest version of Electron.

Please let us know which latest versions of 'ref-napi' and 'ffi-napi' modules can be used with latest version of Electron.

Getting below error on build:

npm run dist command execution:
hUSAuth_Authenticator@1.0.0 dist
electron-builder

```
  • electron-builder  version=22.14.13 os=10.0.19045
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=ffi-napi@4.0.3, ref-napi@3.0.3 platform=win32 arch=x64
  cannot execute  cause=exit status 1`
   ` errorOut=npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path D:\Cyber\Source\Self\Auth\Electron_GUI_Application\node_modules\ffi-napi
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d/s/c node-gyp-build
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@21.2.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
    npm ERR! gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v12.2.3/node-v12.2.3-headers.tar.gz
    npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://artifacts.electronjs.org/headers/v12.2.3/node-v12.2.3-headers.tar.gz?force_headers_dist=1
```